# How do you embed a website to another one?

Tags: html, web, iframe, embed, mirroring

On my website, I want to embed another website into it, so that the two websites are exactly the same. I used the Iframe tag in HTML, although there was a weird border, and because Iframe only embeds, and not mirrors, there would just be a blank spot of 'white' on larger displays. So, I couldn't use that. I could try seeing if my domain host supports Mirroring and see if that works. Please tell me if there's another way.

Comment: Although <embed> doesn't have the same border iframe does (which is good) It still doesn't full screen the webpage, nor mirror it, so that doesn't solve my problem. Removing the 'style' parameter from <embed> doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `<iframe>` tag or `<embed>` tag

```
<embed src="http://www.example.com" style="width:400px; height: 400px;">
<iframe src="https://www.example.com" style="width:400px; height: 400px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<embed>` tag defines a container for an external resource, such as a web page, a picture, a media player, or a plug-in application.

`<embed>` is a good choice but there are drawbacks of using `<embed>`

**Drawback**

- Most browsers no longer support Java Applets and Plug-ins.
- ActiveX controls are no longer supported in any browsers.
- The support for Shockwave Flash has also been turned off in modern
  browsers.

my suggestion is to use `<iframe>` tag.

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" style="width:400px; height: 400px;"></iframe>
```

check the running example
[here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe)

Answer (score 0):

you can use EMBED or IFRAME tag.
iframe is older and embed was introduced in HTML5.
They're different in attributes. check this to learn more:
https://html-shark.com/HTML/EmbeddedObjects.htm