# how to make html webpage a part of website

Tags: html, ionos

I've just created my own website with my own domain with IONOS.

On the side, I had created a webpage which was hosted using XAMP, so currently to view my webpage I have to use the URL `http://localhost/project1/index.html#`

However, I'd like to integrate it into my website if possible?

For example have a section on my webpage where I show a thumbnail of the webpage and when clicked it takes me to `www.mywebsite.co.uk/project1`

I'm not sure how to go about this though?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you embed a website to another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68044486/how-do-you-embed-a-website-to-another-one)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iframe.
See [Html Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP) for more detail about it.

like:

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" title="W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<iframe>` tag specifies an inline frame. An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

```
<iframe src="www.mywebsite.co.uk/project1" title="My HTML Page"></iframe>
```